# Integral of product of two inverse distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^1F_{Y}^{-1}(1-u)F_{Z}^{-1}(1-u)\,du$$
where $F_{Y}^{-1}$ and $F_{Z}^{-1}$ are two generalized inverse cumulative distribution functions. What I mean is
$$F_{Y}^{-1}(u) = \inf\{y \in \mathbb{R}\mid F_Y(y)\geq u \}$$
where $F_Y(y) = P\{Y \leq y\}$ for some random variable $Y$.

We know that if $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, then $F_{Y}^{-1}(1-U) \stackrel{d}{=} Y$. Hence,
$$\int_0^1F_{Y}^{-1}(1-u)\,du = E[F_{Y}^{-1}(1-U)] = E[Y]$$

I couldn't convince myself that this result extends to my problem. It is certainly that not true that if $A \stackrel{d}{=} B$ and $C \stackrel{d}{=} D$, then $E[AC] = E[BD]$. Example: take $A$ standard normal, $C = -A$, $B = -A$, $D=-A$.
This example prevents me from writing the last equality in
$$\int_0^1F_{Y}^{-1}(1-u)F_{Z}^{-1}(1-u)\,du = E[F_{Y}^{-1}(1-U)F_{Z}^{-1}(1-U)] = E[YZ]$$

Can someone please help me clarify this issue?

Comment: Not an answer but some remarks: 1. Each $1-u$ and each $1-U$ could be replaced by $u$ and $U$ respectively. 2. It may happen that $Y$ and $Z$ are integrable but $\int_0^1F_Y^{-1}F_Z^{-1}$ is infinite. 3. For every $F_Y$ and $F_Z$, $\int_0^1F_Y^{-1}F_Z^{-1}\geqslant\int_0^1F_Y^{-1}\int_0^1F_Z^{-1}=E(Y)E(Z)$. 4. The value of $E(F_Y^{-1}(U)F_Z^{-1}(U))$ might be the maximum of $E(Y'Z')$ over every couple $(Y',Z')$ with marginals $F_Y$ and $F_Z$.